# Suppress change-submit trigger while executing form-in trigger in Perforce Helix Core using Java APIs

Tags: perforce, perforce-helix-core

I have written 2 triggers for Perforce Helix Core using Perforce Java APIs:

First one is for change-submit action where I check for Perforce Job association. If a job is not associated, it doesn't allow to proceed with change-submit action.

Second trigger is about Stream Creation (Form-in action), where I check if current user is part of a group which is allowed to create stream or not, and if not, it doesn't allow to proceed with stream creation.

Problem: When a valid user tries to create stream, it fails because the stream creation (form-in action) not only creates stream but also populates it which eventually triggers change-submit operation. And of course at that moment there is no job associated and hence it fails.

Is there a way to suppress change-submit trigger while executing stream creation (form-in) trigger? Or is there a any other approach we can avoid this scenario?

Comment: Why doesn't your change-submit trigger just, say, skip any changelist that consists only of `branch` actions?

Comment: Yes, worked! Checked branch actions on FileSpec. But, would it cause any issue with Branch File(s)?

Comment: What kind of issue?  What's a "Branch File"?